# Can I add my family onto my existing US visa?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, family

I have Valid US Visa and I Want to travel with my Family. How can I issue visa for my family to go with me using my own visa?

Comment: What visa is this?

Comment: It's simple: each person in your family must apply for a separate visa. I don't understand why this was closed.

Comment: @phoog sorry, add your own answer now?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your visa classification you can **add** (*note that the adding is done by the consular officer through the issue of a visa to your dependent, you don't personally physically add them yourself*) your dependents to your visa. For visitors visas you **cannot** add them and they essentially apply as fresh individuals on their own merits.

For H1B and other employment based visas etc, you do that by giving the dependent a copy of your [approved petition](https://www.path2usa.com/samples/sample-h1b-approval-form-I797.jpg) which they submit as evidence/proof for their visa application interviews (that is if you didn't include them in your own petition).

These [visa classifications](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/all-visa-categories.html) include but are not limited to:

> Persons with H-1B visas (for specialty workers **and their spouses and
>   minor children with H-4 visas**), K visas (for fiancees or foreign
>   spouses of US citizens **and their minor children**), L visas (for
>   corporate transferees **& their spouses and minor children**), and V visas
>   (spouses and minor children of lawful permanent residents), O
>   visas (for workers who have extraordinary ability **and their spouses
>   and minor children**), P visas (for athletes, artists or entertainers
>   **and their spouses and minor children**), and E visas (for treaty traders
>   or treaty investors **and their spouses and minor children**)

Typically all these are visas which allow you to stay and work in the USA for extended periods of time, not just ordinary visit.